# Bokeh Unable to replace plot by svg element

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, bokeh

I have a simple bokeh web app where user can upload a csv or excel file and based on the file certain kind of plot will appear. I have implemented a svg spinner for loading notification purpose. Ideally the app should replace blank plot by svg element when user click on upload button and when file gets uploaded successfully then that svg element should again gets replaced by the blank plot.

But i have observed 3 weird behaviors which are:

1. bokeh sometimes remove the plot but svg doesn't get render successfully on first attempt
2. sometime removes plot and shows svg element for a fraction of time when file gets uploaded but it should remove plot as soon as upload button gets clicked
3. sometimes plot gets removed successfully but shows blank screen except left side widgets

But after 1 or 2 attempts bokeh behaves ideally.

Bokeh server version 1.0.4

Please refer below script which reproduce this issue.

```
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, layout, row
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div, Button, RadioButtonGroup, Select, Slider
from bokeh.events import ButtonClick
import io
import base64
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
from bokeh.models import Range1d, PanTool, ResetTool, HoverTool, WheelZoomTool

file_source = ColumnDataSource({'file_contents':[], 'file_name':[]})
data = {}

def file_callback():
    layout = curdoc().get_model_by_name('mainLayout')
    raw_contents = file_source.data['file_contents'][0]
    name = file_source.data['file_name'][0]
    prefix, b64_contents = raw_contents.split(",", 1)
    file_contents = base64.b64decode(b64_contents)
    file_io = io.BytesIO(file_contents)
    curdoc().title = "File Uploading....."
    layout.children.pop()
    layout.children.append(notification)
    if name.endswith('.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(file_io, delimiter="\t")
        df.to_csv('%s'%name, index=False)
        print("csv downloaded successfully")
    else:
        df = pd.read_excel(file_io)
        df.to_excel('%s'%name, index=False)
        print("excell downloaded successfully")
    data['df'] = df
    layout.children.pop()
    layout.children.append(f)
    curdoc().title = "Word Count"    

# file_source.on_change('data', file_callback)

# create widgets
button_1 = Button(label="Browse...", button_type="success")
upload = Button(label="Upload File", button_type="success")
button_1.js_on_click(CustomJS(args=dict(file_source=file_source), code = """
function read_file(filename) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = load_handler;
    reader.onerror = error_handler;
    // readAsDataURL represents the file's data as a base64 encoded string
    reader.readAsDataURL(filename);
}

function load_handler(event) {
    var b64string = event.target.result;
    file_source.data = {'file_contents' : [b64string], 'file_name':[input.files[0].name]};
    file_source.change.emit();
}

function error_handler(evt) {
    if(evt.target.error.name == "NotReadableError") {
        alert("Can't read file!");
    }
}

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
input.onchange = function(){
    if (input.files[0].name.endsWith(".xlsx") || input.files[0].name.endsWith(".csv")) {
        console.log(input.files)
        read_file(input.files[0]);
    } else {
        alert('Please Upload CSV or Excel file');
    }
}
input.click();
"""))

upload.on_click(file_callback)
button_2 = Button(label="Plot")

# put the results in a row
box = widgetbox(button_1, upload, button_2, width=300)
notification = Div(text="""<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0" width="550px" height="500px" viewBox="-430 -430 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve"><g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="#000000" d="M109.25 55.5h-36l12-12a29.54 29.54 0 0 0-49.53 12H18.75A46.04 46.04 0 0 1 96.9 31.84l12.35-12.34v36zm-90.5 17h36l-12 12a29.54 29.54 0 0 0 49.53-12h16.97A46.04 46.04 0 0 1 31.1 96.16L18.74 108.5v-36z"/><animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 64 64" to="360 64 64" dur="720ms" repeatCount="indefinite"/></g></svg>""",width=550,height=500) # display Processing...
f = figure(x_range = [], plot_height=250, title="Some Plot", toolbar_location=None, tools="",name = 'plot')
f.vbar([], top=[], width=0.9, color=Spectral6)
f.y_range.start = 0
f.tools = [PanTool(),ResetTool()]
f.toolbar_location = 'above'
f.plot_width=800
f.plot_height=500

lay = row(box, f, width=800,name='mainLayout')

curdoc().add_root(lay)
curdoc().title = "Word Count"
```